# On iOS, can two Timers be set at the same time, or have a timer fire off an event 0.0083 second later to achieve 120 fps?

Tags: ios, timer, core-animation

It seems like the highest timer rate on iOS is 60 times per second using `CADisplayLink`, which is 0.01666 second each time.  Can two timers be set up at the same time, so that an image can be updated more frequently for its location?

Or, can one timer event handler fire off another timer event 0.00833 second later, so that there is another update in between the 1/60 intervals, to achieve 120 fps?

Comment: I imagine the reason timer rates are limited to 60/sec is due to hardware timer interrupts.  Meaning those two timers will fire at or very near the same time regardless.

Comment: or can we have two threads, one thread doing the screen update as much as possible, and the other thread just taking up the user's events

Comment: The maximum screen refresh rate is 60 FPS on iOS devices, so even if you were able to set up a timer to fire at 120 Hz, you wouldn't be able to update your objects onscreen any faster.

Comment: The display link is already running on a background thread, while UI events come in on the main thread.

Answer (score 2):

Why would you want to achieve 120 fps on a screen that updates 60 times a second?
That would just waste CPU and power. Don't do it.

However, having a timer that fires more often is definitely possible.
Drawing in each of these callbacks is, however, is not possible. (at least using -drawRect:, don't know about OpenGL).

Comment: Firing a timer that often, especially with complex drawing going on, is most definitely not possible.

Comment: Plus it doesn't make any sense after all. Not even for the physics computation of games.

Comment: first, I am not so familiar with the hardware side, graphics card, or GPU, whether it is "limited to 60fps by the hardware" and nothing can go beyond that. One motivation for the original question was, some HDTV are 60fps, and you see the images moving in tiny steps (not smooth motion), so some HDTV has 120 fps or 240 fps (they call it 120 Hz)... so that's why the original question

Comment: @太極者無極而生 Sure, there are screens that update with more than 60Hz, and thus can display more than 60 fps. Current iOS devices only refresh with a frequency of 60Hz though.

Answer (score 2):

You can't do this for a number of reasons. First, there's a hard cap at 60fps due to hardware limitations. Second, NSTimer is not nearly accurate enough for this sort of thing. From the Timer Programming Topics - Timer documentation (bold added for emphasis):

> **Timing Accuracy**
>
> A timer is not a real-time mechanism; it fires only when one of the
>   run loop modes to which the timer has been added is running and able
>   to check if the timer’s firing time has passed. Because of the various
>   input sources a typical run loop manages, **the effective resolution of
>   the time interval for a timer is limited to on the order of 50-100
>   milliseconds**. If a timer’s firing time occurs while the run loop is in
>   a mode that is not monitoring the timer or during a long callout, the
>   timer does not fire until the next time the run loop checks the timer.
>   Therefore, **the actual time at which the timer fires potentially can be
>   a significant period of time after the scheduled firing time**.